# image_tag in markdown with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, paperclip, markdown, rdiscount

I'm adding images in the text of my blog articles.

I have the BlogImage model:

```
class BlogImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :blog_id, :caption, :image

  belongs_to :blog

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { big: "1200X630>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "300x300>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"

  validates_attachment_presence :image
  validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 3.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
end
```

and my article body is rendered with:

```
    :markdown
      #{blog.body}
```

The markdown is handled by the gem `rdiscount`

I would like to be able to write a tag in my markdown, (such as `[image_name]` or similar) so that this would be automatically converted upon rendering with the right image tag.

I don't know where to start with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert an image with RDiscount using syntax like:

```
![GitHub Favicon](https://github.com/favicon.ico =16x16)
```

The title is required (but can be empty). The size is optional.

Comment: yeah that might be a solution, although paperclip generates complex filenames containing hashes, and I don't want to be searching for these complicate urls. So I'd really prefer something like: `(![GitHub Favicon]([favicon] =16x16)` and have the view replace that with the right url.